# Get account id from private/secret key

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

I added a way to generate an address from PK58 by possessing the private key, but is there anyway to get the readable account id?

For example, input my private and/or secret key and get `account.testnet` if they have one, instead of a hex kind of address.

What are the options to get the account id?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve named account name from within the private/secret key.

However, there is a way to do it from the public one by using the public access of NEAR Explorer database.

You can find the shared access to the databases in [NEAR Indexer for Explorer repo](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#shared-public-access)

After you have connected you execute the query:

```
SELECT account_id FROM access_keys WHERE public_key = 'ed25519:5HApjDQKtYQQhWURi2zQ8rRrVfJftkUDKLjyVejhLBwG';

      account_id
-----------------------
 py2sfxwe5q16p.testnet
```

Refer to the [Database structure scheme](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#database-structure)

Comment: How about calling an RPC or something to get the named account, setting up a database call could slow down my app

Comment: RPC doesn't have any endpoints for this. Actually, the nearcore internal database doesn't even allow creating endpoints like this